# How to add a smooth line using ggplot2 in a plot with 2 different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot with 2 different datasets and a smooth line of each scatter to compare them.

I can do it separately but for some reason, I can not do it when both are in the same plot (I know it might be my lack of coding knowledge)

I am trying this maybe someone can point my mistake

```
df1 <- data.frame("x1"=1:25, "y1"=rnorm(25))
df2 <- data.frame("x2"=1:25, "y2"=rnorm(25))
ggplot()+geom_point(data=df1,aes(x=x1,y=y1),size=2,shape=23,color="blue")+
  geom_point(data=df2,aes(x=x2,y=y2),size=2,shape=23,color="red")+geom_smooth(se=F)
```

Thanks for all the help

Edit: I added workable data as suggested

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same as for the other `geom`s. Pass each dataframe to a separate `geom_smooth` and define the mapping or the aesthetics:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame("x1"=1:25, "y1"=rnorm(25))
df2 <- data.frame("x2"=1:25, "y2"=rnorm(25))
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=df1,aes(x=x1,y=y1),size=2,shape=23,color="blue")+
  geom_point(data=df2,aes(x=x2,y=y2),size=2,shape=23,color="red")+
  geom_smooth(data=df1,aes(x=x1,y=y1), se=F) +
  geom_smooth(data=df2,aes(x=x2,y=y2), se=F)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think I tried that before but for some reason did not work. I must probably forget about the aes command